# indefinite integral substitution trickery

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

[image: find **indefinite** integral using substitution]
I want to find the indefinite integral using **substitution** on the above.  I needed a few sets of eyes and also maybe the appropriate dunce cap if need be.  I am wondering if I am on the right track, or if I am missing crucial steps and or points to making the solution explanatory?  They don't call me captain confused for nothing.  Here is the work that I have completed for this problem...
[image: capn' work with substitution pre critics stack]

Comment: Did you try to compute the derivative of your result ? It does not match the integrand.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int( x^2 + 5)^4\Big( 2x\,dx\Big) - 5 \int (x^2-5)^4\,dx
$$
The first integral becomes
$$
\int u^5 \, du.
$$
The second integral could be treated simply by expanding $(x^2-5)^4$, but that would be inconvenient if we had $(x^2-5)^{40}$.  My first thought for that is $(\sqrt{5}\sec\theta)^2 - 5)^{40} = (\tan^2\theta)^{40}$, and then $dx = \sqrt{5} \sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$. etc.

Comment: I am pretty confused.  I am sorry, I am trying to find similar examples to what this problem asks but am coming up empty?

Comment: My advice: Slow and steady wins the race.Not only you should look, but *look around* and never *overlook*. In math, correctness and accuracy are more important than speed(if its not a speed contest). Take your own sweet cool time, and if someone hurries you, ask them to be patient with the extra time you need.