# Integral $\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt[] {3-x^3} } \operatorname d \! x$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt[] {3-x^3} } \operatorname d \! x$$

I have the above indefinite integral problem with substitution and I wanted to see if I could get a double check from the masses just in case I am missing anything crucial to making the final solution that much more explanatory!  Thank you for your help and I apologize for the chicken scratch again!

Here are the steps I have taken the time to complete and am requesting a double check/critique of:

[image: worked out solution before double checkers]

$$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3-x^3}} \,dx =
\begin{vmatrix}
u=3-x^3\\
du=-3x^2 dx
\end{vmatrix} =
\int -\frac13 \int \frac1{\sqrt u} du \overset{(1)}=
-\frac{2\sqrt u}3+C \overset{(2)}=
-\frac{2\sqrt{3-x^3}}3+C$$

(1) $\int\frac1{\sqrt u}=2\sqrt u+C$
(2) susbstitute $u$

Comment: Differentiate, and you will see that you are right.

Comment: Changed your first image to a Mathjax, look up the FAQ for the site on how to do latex or google Mathjax.

Comment: Criticism: Somewhere you write $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\,du=2\sqrt{u}$, which is not quite true, and then, you write $=-\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{u}+C$, which is definitely not true, since $2\sqrt{u}$ is not $-\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{u}+C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ok, but a small thing. When you wrote

$$ - \frac23 \sqrt u + C $$

you mentally imagined the first part, but did not put it down. Just say " integral =" or some such thing on the left hand side so those who may read sequentially cannot detect the omission.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3-x^3}}dx$$
let $$u = 3 - x^3$$
$$-\frac{du}{3} = x^2dx$$
$$-\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du = -\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{u} +C = -\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3 - x^3} +C$$

Comment: could you take a look at this one:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193462/indefinite-integral-substitution-trickery