# exact value using geometry calculus double check

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-6}^6 \sqrt{36-x^2} \, dx$$

I have the above integral on the interval [-6,6]. I also have taken the time to work out the steps on paper and have included them below.  I wish to ask if you folks can see if the steps I have taken are correct or not?  If I am missing any crucial steps that make the solution unclear then please correct me!  Thank you!

[image: the steps captain confused has completed prior to double check peer review]

Comment: As in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193503/integral-int-fracx2-sqrt-3-x3-operatorname-d-x, please edit your question so it will be readable. Scans are rarely welcome on this site.

Comment: ...Did you photograph your monitor?

Comment: @Regret Yeah its the quickest way I know how to enter things in here.  I am sorry, I will try to improve my skills in the future!  Not trying to irritate any one's eyes.  I just am looking for a review of the steps I took.

Comment: @CaptainConfused: I think you should take a look at [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It explains how you can format math on this site.

Comment: @Regret I will.  I have been working on math all day.  Trying to get through it.  I have a degree in software development, I just am in need of double check my hand writing is that bad that you can't see if i have the right answer, or you just don't know about calculus enough to double check?

Comment: @CaptainConfused You have a degree in software development but didn't think of making a printscreen and photographed your monitor instead?

Comment: @CaptainConfused: Well, your answer is correct. But you use a lot of knowledge about circles to get it. If you are allowed to use this knowledge, then your method is fine.

Comment: @5xum Not after working on math for 12 hours straight.  My brain is fried. So if you don't have a degree in software development there might be hope for you yet.  Besides.. I don't use Android like you must. ;)

Comment: If you graph it on a calculator you see that this is the radius of the half circle

Comment: This question shouldn't have been downvoted. There is nothing wrong with scans, as longs as it is readable, which it is in this case. This is actually a well-posed question.

Comment: If the persons likes to take a photo of his screen (and it is clear) and it makes calculus fun for him, I don't see why that shouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, I will first say that your answer is correct. However, I do not see why you let $x=6$. To understand the problem completely. If $y=f(x)$ is a function, then it can be represented as a graph in Carterian Coordinate Plane. And the expression $\int_a^b{f(x)}dx$ represents the total area bounded by the curve $f(x)$ starting from $x=a$ to $x=b$. Now, note that in the problem $f(x)=\sqrt{36-x^2}$, its graph is the upper part of the circle centered at origin with radius 6. Using the interpretation of the definite integral stated above , we see that the integral that we are solving is just the area of the upper part of the circle with radius 6. From here your solution follows.

Note however that you can also use trigo substitution in solving the integral. The main disadvantage of interpreting definite integrals as area is that what if the graph of $f$ is not a geometric figure whose area is easy to compute? So I would suggest try also use other methods. But you are correct. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah.. this was how the calculus example showed it with the r= the radius.

Comment: I agree, indeed calculus is an interesting subject